# Write the frequency of each number in column into next column in bash

Tags: bash

I have a column with different numbers in each row in a text file. Now, I want the frequency of each number into a new column. And the similar rows should be deleted, to have only each unique number in the first column and the frequency in the second column.

Input:

```
0.32832977
0.31647876
0.31482627
0.31447645
0.31447645
0.31396809
0.31281157
0.312004
0.31102326
0.30771822
0.30560062
0.30413213
0.30373717
0.29636685
0.29622422
0.29590765
0.2949896
0.29414582
0.28841901
0.28820667
0.28291832
0.28243792
0.28156429
0.28043638
0.27872239
0.27833349
0.27825573
0.27669023
0.27645657
0.27645657
0.27645657
0.27645657
```

Output:

```
0.32832977 1
0.31647876 1
0.31482627 1
0.31447645 2
0.31396809 1
0.31281157 1
0.312004   1
0.31102326 1
0.30771822 1
0.30560062 1
0.30413213 1
0.30373717 1 
0.29636685 1
0.29622422 1
0.29590765 1
0.2949896  1
0.29414582 1
0.28841901 1
0.28820667 1
0.28291832 1
0.28243792 1
0.28156429 1
0.28043638 1
0.27872239 1
0.27833349 1
0.27825573 1
0.27669023 1
0.27645657 4
```

I tried this command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
awk -F '|' '{freq[$1]++} END{for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}' file
```

Comment: If your input file does not use "|" as field separator (your sample does not), then why set it with -F ?

Comment: Can you have trailing zeroes or other ways to represent the same number as different text strings (e.g. scientific notation, leading `+` signs, etc.)? If yes do you want to merge the different forms of the same number or is it OK if they are considered as different numbers? Note: the two answers, including the one you accepted, will consider them as different numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Awk is an overkill IMO here, the built-in tools will do the work just fine:

```
sort -n file | uniq -c | sort
```

Output:

1 0.32832977

2 0.31447645

4 0.27645657

Comment: The `-n` should go to the second `sort`, not the first one.

Comment: Overkill is maybe a bit exaggerated. First, the OP want their frequency in the second column, not the first one. So you would need something more to swap the output columns (`awk`?). Next, on a pure performance point of view, it could well be that one single `awk` process is better than 3 or 4 (`sort` and `uniq` are not `bash` built-ins). At least, I think we would need to do some tests.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this would be the `awk` solution (no need to set the input field separator to `|` if your sample input is representative).

```
awk '{f[$0]++} END{for (i in f) print i, f[i]}' input.txt
```

```
0.28820667 1
0.30560062 1
0.312004 1
0.28156429 1
0.28291832 1
0.29636685 1
0.31447645 2
0.30373717 1
0.31482627 1
:
```

You can, however, set the **output** field separator to `|` or (as I did here) to a tab character, to format the output

```
awk '{f[$0]++} END{OFS="\t"; for (i in f) print i, f[i]}' input.txt
```

```
0.28820667  1
0.30560062  1
0.312004    1
0.28156429  1
0.28291832  1
0.29636685  1
0.31447645  2
0.30373717  1
0.31482627  1
:
```